# Add pdf metadata with Lualatex (without hyperref)

Tags: luatex, pdf, metadata

I would like to add pdf metadata to my output with lualatex. I know how to do it with hyperref, but I only like to include that package if I need it.  Is there another way? I can use `\pdfinfo` with pdflatex, and a `\special` with xelatex, but I can't get either to work with lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Works with pdflatex but gives error with lualatex:
%\pdfinfo{ /Title (My Story) /Author (Me) }

% Works with xelatex, but does not work with lualatex:
%\special { pdf:docinfo << /Title (My Story) /Author (Me)>> }

\begin{document}
I lived.
\end{document}
```

Comment: See section 3.2.2 of LuaTeX's manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with using the primitives is that they are not managed. That means that if your code for one or the other reason set the info more than once you end with duplicate entries in the Info dictionary:

```
<<  /Title (My Story) /Author (Me)  /Title (My other Story) /Author (some one else) >>
```

This is not allowed.

That's one of the reasons why the PDF management exists. It takes care of this. With its low-level commands you can insert the title like this:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{Info}{Title}{(My~Story)}
\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{Info}{Author}{(Me)}
\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{Info}{Title}{(My~other~Story)}
\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{Info}{Author}{(Someone)}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
aaa

\end{document}
```

The last setting will win. Be aware that with this it is your task to ensure that the string is valid in PDF, so you must add parentheses and escape non-ascii etc.

More easy it is with the new title module in latex-lab. This requires a current, up-to-date tex system:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=title}
\documentclass{article}
\title{my story}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
aaa
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooo, is this the way of the future (tl2024)? It looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: @dedded Yes, we are integrating a _lot_ into the kernel - but it's not easy work, so baby steps

Comment: @dedded `\DocumentMetadata` is already in texlive 2023,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but the title module is brand new ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I chose my words carefully:-)

Answer (score 2):

With Udi Fogiel's helpful comment I resolved it with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifluatex
  % From section 3.2.2 of Luatex manual:
  \pdfextension info { /Title (My Story) /Author (Me) }
\else\ifxetex
  \special { pdf:docinfo << /Title (My Story) /Author (Me)>> }
\else\ifpdftex
  \pdfinfo{ /Title (My Story) /Author (Me) }
\fi\fi\fi

\begin{document}
I lived.
\end{document}
```

Comment: using tex primitives in this way does make it harder to make the document portable across engines or work with Packages such as the latex tagging code that need to manage global document metadata.

Comment: Is there an alternative? I can protect it against other engines with `\ifluatex` , but don't know anything about tagging.